# Is it possible to use Linq and lambdas without including a System.Linq namespace?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Some time ago, I've been working on a quite twisted project - I could only write the code in the single scope and it would be later put in a C# function (by another module).

I could only use namespaces which were declared before (I had no influence on them) and could only use variables from the scope I worked in.
Because of that, I wasn't able to change the headers and included libraries.

The problem came when I wanted to operate on generic collections - I couldn't use neither lambda expressions, nor LINQ - I simply wasn't
able to put `using System.Linq;` , as I had no access to the file header.

I had to do only a simple thing and it was easy to manage without LINQ or lambda. However, after that I was wondering what would happen, if I had to use some
more complex operations on IEnumerable. 
From that, there comes my question:

**Is it possible to use LINQ or lambdas without changing the file header and adding new namespaces?**

Let's say that we have a `List<int> _Numbers = new List<int>();`. Let it be filled with some numbers.
Now I want to select all the even numbers from it.

With `using System.Linq;` in the header, the solution is obvious:

```
List<int> _NewList = _Numbers.Where(n => n % 2 == 0).ToList();
```

or

```
List<int> _NewList = (from _Number in _Numbers where _Number % 2 == 0 select _Number).ToList();
```

But without LINQ included, how can I achieve this? 
My first guess would be something like:

```
List<int> _NewList = System.Linq. // ??? What to add here?
```

I am aware that the problem is rather exotic, and it's very unusual to go this way, but I'm just curious and I've found no information about this case.

Comment: `System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(_NewList, n => n % 2 == 0)`

Comment: @nsinreal - thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. Add that as an answer and I'll mark it as correct ;)

Comment: You can also include 'using' statements within a class's namespace declaration. Is that still outside of the scope you have access to?

Comment: I think extension methods are just a hack to make up for the lack of multiple inheritance.

Comment: The reason why nsinreal's solution is correct is that Linq (Linq-to-Objects) consists of extension methods (like `Where`) placed in a `public static class Enumerable` inside the `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: @Sam Could you extend `IEnumerable<>` type just as beautifully with multiple inheritance if no extension methods existed? I am talking about the Linq as an application of extension methods.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, no, in `Queryable` class. There is a difference, Enumerable class methods accepts `Func`s (compiled code), `Queryable` class method accepts `Expression<Func<..>>` (code stored as abstract syntax tree, that can be rewrited/processed/etc)

Comment: @Sam - no, I could only reach the scope inside the function. That is the issue of a third-party API which was no longer developed and was full of twists like that.

Comment: @nsinreal Yeah, I know, that's why I wrote Linq-to-Objects. When the "source" you query is just a `List<>` in managed memory, you use delegates and `Enumerable` methods. Of course if you query something like a SQL database, you would hold your lambdas as expression trees and have some magical "machine" translate the expressions into true SQL that the database server understands. Then using the methods in `Queryable` static class.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, thanks; you have a good point. I should have aimed my comment at LINQ rather than extension methods

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen sorry, I didn't know that Linq-to-Objects works around IEnumerable, I always thinked that it works aroud IQueryable. Sorry, again

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Without the `using` directive, methods like `.Where`, `.Select`, will not resolve. That means that LINQ *the language part* will not work. You would have to code it long-hand (and backwards!):

```
List<int> _NewList = System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(
    System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(_Numbers, _Number => _Number % 2 == 0)
);
```

Note that this becomes increasing complex for longer examples with groups, orders, "let"s, joins etc. Unless you are doing something fairly simple, it would be advisable to just find a way to add the `using` directive.

Note, however, that if `_Numbers` is a `List<T>`, you can just use (for this single example):

```
List<int> _NewList = _Numbers.FindAll(_Number => _Number % 2 == 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, it explained a lot. I know about FindAll(), but as far as I'm aware, it only works with List, and I was looking for more universal way.

Answer (score 3):

You can write such code:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(_NewList, n => n % 2 == 0)
```

But, be careful: if your class implements interface `IQueryable<T>`, code above will do the work, but more slower.

```
System.Linq.Queryable.Where(_NewList, n => n % 2 == 0)
```

Because `IQueryable` is the way to produce C# in other DSL language, like SQL. With other `where` conditions your SQL server can choose needed elements as fast as it can. But if you working with `IEnumerable` or `System.Linq.Enumerable` there no be optimise on server-side, you'll got a full list of items, they all will be loaded to the memory and filtered in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Not very clear why you can not access file "header", but if the issue that you can not type in the begining of the file `using` dirrective, you *can* still use full qualified name of the type, like:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable(...)
```

To make this work, you naturally, need to include also correct references.

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

Comment: I couldn't access the file header, that was the issue of the APi I was working with. I know that I could add System.Linq. in the scope, but I didn't know how to futher evaluate it.